# Cannot create Echo (laravel-echo) instance in react (Next.JS)

Tags: laravel, next.js

Since it is a next.js app, I do not have `resources/js/bootstrap.js`

I am trying to create an Echo instance, but it throws an error:

```
Server Error
ReferenceError: Pusher is not defined
```

```
  13 | import Echo from "laravel-echo";
  14 | 
> 15 | const echo = new Echo({
     |           ^
  16 | broadcaster: "pusher",
  17 | key: process.env.PUSHER_APP_KEY,
  18 | wsHost: process.env.PUSHER_HOST,
```

My component

```
import Pusher from "pusher-js";
import Echo from "laravel-echo";

const echo = new Echo({
  broadcaster: "pusher",
  key: process.env.PUSHER_APP_KEY,
  wsHost: process.env.PUSHER_HOST,
  wsPort: process.env.PUSHER_PORT ?? 80,
  wssPort: process.env.PUSHER_PORT ?? 443,
  forceTLS: (process.env.PUSHER_SCHEME ?? "https") === "https",
  encrypted: true,
  enabledTransports: ["ws", "wss"],
});
```

If I paste code from `resources/js/bootstrap.js`

```
import Echo from 'laravel-echo';

import Pusher from 'pusher-js';
window.Pusher = Pusher;

window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: "pusher",
    key: process.env.PUSHER_APP_KEY,
    wsHost: process.env.PUSHER_HOST,
    wsPort: process.env.PUSHER_PORT ?? 80,
    wssPort: process.env.PUSHER_PORT ?? 443,
    forceTLS: (process.env.PUSHER_SCHEME ?? "https") === "https",
    encrypted: true,
    enabledTransports: ["ws", "wss"],
  });
```

I get the following error.

```
Server Error
ReferenceError: window is not defined
```

```
  27 | 
  28 | import Pusher from 'pusher-js';
> 29 | window.Pusher = Pusher;
  30 | 
  31 | window.Echo = new Echo({
  32 | broadcaster: "pusher",
```

Does anyone know how to use laravel-echo with next.js?